# How to create a subscribtion link to ICS/Webcal calendars?

Tags: outlook, calendar, icalendar, webcal

ICS files on Android are downloaded by default an not opened by the calendar app. When using Google Calendar or Outlook on desktops, ICS files need to be imported manually after downloading. What link format is required for the ICS files to be automatically added to the desired calendar?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of the different link formats:

#### Desktop/Android/Apple Calendar

```
webcal://LINK_TO_ICS_FILES
```

**Example:**

```
webcal://www.officeholidays.com/ics/various
```

#### Google Calendar

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=WEBCAL_LINK_URL_ENCODED
```

**Example:**

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=webcal%3A%2F%2Fnextcloud.kni.tirol%2Fremote.php%2Fdav%2Fpublic-calendars%2FTYESMsejwnMdmqaX%3Fexport
```

#### Outlook 365

```
https://outlook.office.com/owa?path=%2Fcalendar%2Faction%2Fcompose&rru=addsubscription&url=WEBCAL_LINK_URL_ENCODED&name=CALENDAR_NAME
```

**Example:**

```
https://outlook.office.com/owa?path=%2Fcalendar%2Faction%2Fcompose&rru=addsubscription&url=webcal%3A%2F%2Fwww.officeholidays.com%2Fics%2Fvarious&name=My%20Calendar
```

#### Outlook Live

```
https://outlook.live.com/owa?path=%2Fcalendar%2Faction%2Fcompose&rru=addsubscription&url=WEBCAL_LINK_URL_ENCODED&name=CALENDAR_NAME
```

**Example:**

```
https://outlook.live.com/owa?path=%2Fcalendar%2Faction%2Fcompose&rru=addsubscription&url=webcal%3A%2F%2Fwww.officeholidays.com%2Fics%2Fvarious&name=My%20Calendar
```

#### Download .ics file

```
https://LINK_TO_ICS_FILES
```

**Example:**

```
https://www.officeholidays.com/ics/various
```